# python csv fieldnames error

Tags: python, excel, csv

I was doing some export to csv and I have a problem with the fieldnames.
I want 3 rows of "fieldnames"

```
Row 1 : Field 1:empty    ; Field 2:"YEAR" , Field3:"2017"
Row 2 : Field 1:empty    ; Field 2:"MONTH", Field3: month.number
Row 3 : Field 1:"STATION"; Field 2:"CODE" , Field3: day.number
```

Since I don't know how to joint the cells, so that 2017 merges all the cells on top of the 12/365 cells, or each month (Jan for example) merges the 31 cells on top of the days... I'm printing each cell with 2017 or Jan (31 times) 
Feb (28 times) etc.

```
import csv
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

HYear= [' ','Year','2017']
HMonth=[' ','Month','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug',
       'Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
HDay=  ['Station','Code','01','02','03','04','05','06','07',
      '08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18',
      '19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']

#VARs
today = datetime.today()
num_day = today.day
num_month = today.month

mon1 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 1)[1] ###31
mon2 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 2)[1]+mon1###59
mon3 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 3)[1]+mon2###90
mon4 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 4)[1]+mon3
mon5 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 5)[1]+mon4
mon6 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 6)[1]+mon5
mon7 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 7)[1]+mon6
mon8 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 8)[1]+mon7
mon9 = calendar.monthrange(2017, 9)[1]+mon8
mon10= calendar.monthrange(2017,10)[1]+mon9
mon11= calendar.monthrange(2017,11)[1]+mon10
mon12= calendar.monthrange(2017,12)[1]+mon11

#Days in Year
for i in range(1,num_month):
  d = calendar.monthrange(2017, i)[1]
  num_day+=sum((0, d))
days_year = num_day###135 or so

#to CSV
def csv_dict_writer(path, fieldnames, data):
  with open(path, "wb") as out_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in data:
      writer.writerow(row)

#####Headers
heady="%s,%s"%(HYear[0],HYear[1])
headm="%s,%s"%(HMonth[0],HMonth[1])
headd="%s,%s"%(HDay[0],HDay[1])

#####Adding more content to the headers
for i in range(2,days_year+2):###2-367
  if i>1:
    heady+=",%s"%HYear[2]
  if i in range(2,mon1+2):###2-33
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[2]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i]
  elif i in range(mon1+2,mon2+2):###33-61
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[3]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon1]
  elif i in range(mon2 +2,mon3 +2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[4]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon2]
  elif i in range(mon3 +2,mon4 +2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[5]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon3]
  elif i in range(mon4 +2,mon5 +2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[6]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon4]
  elif i in range(mon5 +2,mon6 +2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[7]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon5]
  elif i in range(mon6 +2,mon7 +2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[8]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon6]
  elif i in range(mon7 +2,mon8 +2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[9]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon7]
  elif i in range(mon8 +2,mon9 +2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[10]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon8]
  elif i in range(mon9 +2,mon10+2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[11]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon9]
  elif i in range(mon10+2,mon11+2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[12]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon10]
  elif i in range(mon10+2,mon12+2):
    headm+=",%s"%HMonth[13]
    headd+=",%s"%HDay[i-mon11]

print heady
print headm
print headd

###Creating CSV
if __name__ == "__main__":
  data=[heady.split(","),
        headm.split(","),
        headd.split(",")]
  my_list = []
  fieldnames = data[0]
  for values in data[1:]:
      inner_dict = dict(zip(fieldnames, values))
      my_list.append(inner_dict)
  path = "dict_output.csv"
  csv_dict_writer(path, fieldnames, my_list)
```

After running the program what I get in the variables heady, headm and headd is: (print each)

```
#Print Header Year
 ,Year,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017

#Print Header Month
 ,Month,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Feb,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Mar,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,Apr,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May,May

#Print Header Day
Station,Code,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

But, what I get as headers in the csv is:

```
Row 1: empty, Year, 2017, 2017 ... (correct)
Row 2: Empty, Month, May, May ... (should be Jan not May)
Row 3-360+: Station, Code, 15, 15 ... (should be 01, 02, ..,31, 01, 02... and so on)
```

Any Suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

PS: The output is like

```
empty,   YEAR, 2017, 2017, 2017....*365
empty,  MONTH, Jan, Jan, Jan...*31, Feb, Feb...*28.....
STATION, CODE, 01, 02, 03..., 31, 01, 02,...,28, 01.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modifying your csv writer method and main to get a list and write it to your file!

```
#to CSV
def csv_writer(path, data):
  with open(path, "wb") as out_file:
    for row in data:
      out_file.write(','.join(row))
      out_file.write('\n')


###Creating CSV
if __name__ == "__main__":
  data=[heady.split(","),
        headm.split(","),
        headd.split(",")]
  #data = zip(*data)
  print data
  path = "dict_output.csv"
  csv_writer(path, data)
```

Sample Output:

```
,Year,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,..
 ,Month,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,..
Station,Code,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,..
```

Comment: Thanks man, the csv now has the data I wanted but they are printed in 3 columns, but the data is the header in 3 rows, how to change it?

Comment: Can your share the sample output expected!

Comment: Can you edit your question without mentioning Row1 and stuff.. that is only include the contents expected.

Comment: The desired output is in the last part of the question

Comment: commenting out the zip part in the above answer should do the trick!